# javascript atob("CDA=") doesn't provide the expected behaviour (at least on Chrome 32)

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm trying to convert the base64 encoded string "`CDA=`" into a binary buffer, using JavaScript. I have tried calling the function `atob`, but the result is always an empty array.

I have tried `atob` with character strings, that I encoded with `btoa`, and `atob` provides the expected result. So it seems that it doesn't always fail, but probably only when the base64 string represent a binary data. From the internet, I see that binary data also should be managed... Does anyone have an explanation to this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atob()` returns a string not an array.

Your Base64 string is `0x8 0x30` which is interpreted as `<backspace><zero>` when you *look* at it and see:

```
> window.atob("CDA=")
  "0"
```

However both bytes are present:

```
> window.atob("CDA=").charCodeAt(0)
  8

> window.atob("CDA=").charCodeAt(1)
  48
```

If you want an array, see [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript).